# Make the bash resource wait until the command it's running finishes

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying automate an installation using chef.

```
bash "install something" do
  user "root"
  cwd "/tmp"
  code <<-EOH
    ./runinstaller
  EOH
end
```

This works perfectly and the tool gets installed. But the installation runs even after chef-client has finished successfully. So basically, chef-client succeeds and exits as soon as run installer starts. I wasn't the bash resource to wait till the installer is done and then exit. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: if you run `./runinstaller` from the command-line, what happens?  Does it return immediately?

Comment: no it does what it is supposed to do.. but even if i press ctrl+c it gives me the control back but it still runs in the background. I can see the files being coping. So I guess the command it self is configured to run in the background.

Comment: To me it sounds like `./runinstaller` has some logic built in to detect wether the process running it is another process or a terminal/bash. And to switch its mode based on that (maybe in combination with certain flags or params). Your best option is to dive deeper into the documentation of the installer: chef is most probably not the issue here.

Answer (score -1):

The bash resource, and all Chef command execution, is entirely synchronous. You can't run stuff in the background even if you tried.

Comment: If I am not mistaken you can run a command which itself spawns background processes, the main command would then exit status 0, yet the processes it spawned will contintue to run. In the background. Is that not the case?

Comment: Sure, but Chef neither knows nor cares about that. Anything Chef itself runs will block execution until it returns. Similarly you could use a ruby_block to spin up a thread if you want to be technical.

Comment: I agree coderanger and I am not even trying to run it in the background but its quite evident for the following reasons . 1) When i install it manually (without chef) the entire process takes around 5 mins and then there are around 30-40 folders created. 2) Using chef the same thing gets over within 3 seconds and as soon as the chef run is complete i can see only 1 or 2 folders but again after 3-4 minutes all the folders are created. if suppose I have another recipe that makes use of these folders, my chef-client run would fail.

Comment: I am running oracle fusion middleware installers (ODI, AIA etc) in silent mode.

Comment: It sounds like that script/executable is doing exactly what berkes mentioned and backgrounding itself. You should check if there is a command line option to the installer to disable this behavior.